# How can I wp query for jQuery items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to post query in wordpress jQuery so that populated single item ...my jQuery is shown below:

```
jQuery("#nanoGallery1").nanoGallery({thumbnailWidth:120,thumbnailHeight:120,
            items: [
                {
                    src: 'demonstration/image_01.jpg',      // image url
                    srct: 'demonstration/image_01t.jpg',    // thumbnail url
                    title: 'image 1',                               // thumbnail title
                    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                    title_FR: 'image 1 (fr)',
                    description_FR : 'description image 1 (fr)'
                },
                {
                    src: 'demonstration/image_02.jpg',
                    srct: 'demonstration/image_02t.jpg',
                    title: 'image 2' ,
                    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                    title_FR: 'image 2 (fr)',
                    description_FR : 'description image 2 (fr)'
                },
                {
                    src: 'demonstration/image_03.jpg',
                    srct: 'demonstration/image_03t.jpg',
                    title: 'image 3' ,
                    //title: 'image 3 - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
                    title_FR: 'image 3 (fr)',
                    description_FR : 'description image 3 (fr)'
                }
                ],
                thumbnailHoverEffect:[{name:'imageScaleIn80'},{'name':'descriptionAppear','delay':300},{'name':'borderLighter'}],               
                thumbnailLabel:{display:true,position:'overImageOnBottom'},
        viewerDisplayLogo:true,
        theme:'light',
        fnViewerInfo:myViewerInfo
            });
```

How can i wp query single item like:

```
{
                        src: 'demonstration/image_01.jpg',      // image url
                        srct: 'demonstration/image_01t.jpg',    // thumbnail url
                        title: 'image 1',                               // thumbnail title
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                        title_FR: 'image 1 (fr)',
                        description_FR : 'description image 1 (fr)'
                    },
```

Please suggest how to use function for this query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but I think what you're looking for is AJAX! :)

By default, WordPress has an admin-ajax.php file which you can send AJAX calls to. You can create a hook that is linked to your own custom function in which you can do the stuff you want – like getting the gallery item – and send it back to the client. Then you can pass a value to your AJAX call, called 'action'. When admin-ajax.php is getting a POST request with the action you 'hooked', your custom function is being executed.

Have a look at the links below for a more detailed explanation:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: How can multiple dynamically this{
                        src: 'demonstration/image_01.jpg',      // image url
                        srct: 'demonstration/image_01t.jpg',    // thumbnail url
                        title: 'image 1',                               // thumbnail title
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                        title_FR: 'image 1 (fr)',
                        description_FR : 'description image 1 (fr)'
                    },